# Different files after copying data with Perl in Windows7 and 8.1

Tags: windows, perl, file

I have a file (1.pdf) which is 1mb.
I have a simple Perl script, that reads the data by chunks from the file and writes then every chink into the new file.
After checking the weights of two files - they are different in about 14kb.

In Linux Ubuntu 15 and Mac OS 10.9.5 works perfect.
The problem is only in Win7 x32, Win8.1 x64 and Win7 x64.

I need to process the file (of course) before writing into the new one, but the simple basic operation of reading from a file + writing them into the new one does not work in WIN OS. Sometimes the OS "composes" new bytes for me, sometimes removes.

The script we use is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "test.pdf";

#Creating an output file
open ("F", ">", $filename) || die "Could not create an output file $filename: $!\n";
close F;

my $file = "1.pdf";
open my $upf, "<", $file or die "Could not read from the DATA file\n";


   open ("FOUT", ">>", $filename) || die "Could not write into the output file: $!";
        binmode FOUT;
        while (read($upf, my $data, 1024)) {
           print FOUT $data;
        }
   close FOUT;
close $upf;

print "DONE!";
```

Is it connected with some specific files creation method in Windows?
NB: creation of the file after the comment "Creating an output file" does not make any impact on the result.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Are the bytes that are added and removed `\r`'s?

Comment: @mob I do not know as it is binary file. The same situation continues with ANY binary file (notwithstanding it is image, pdf, music or else). I do not know what the symbol it removes or adds. If it is ёкб what then can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default Perl IO layer on Windows systems is `:crlf`, which converts the CR LF sequence to just LF on input, and reverses the conversion on output. It's done so that a Perl program running on a Windows system and reading and writing Windows files performs identically if it is run on a Linux (or OS X) system and works with files native to that platform

Because of this your `read` operation is missing 14,000 CR characters, and because you have used `binmode` on the output file handle they are not replaced

The proper solution is to use `binmode` on the input file handle as well, or you could open it in `:raw` mode, which has the same effect

Your program should look like this. I've added `use autodie` so that I don't have to write code to check the status of each file IO operation like `open`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my ( $infile, $outfile) = qw/ 1.pdf test.pdf /;

open my $in_fh,  '<:raw', $infile;
open my $out_fh, '>:raw', $outfile;

while ( my $size = read($in_fh, my $data, 1024) ) {
   print $out_fh $data;
}

print "DONE!\n";
```

You could also use [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html), which bypasses the Perl IO system, so the `:crlf` layer is irrelevant